# v-model and computed property inconsistent behaviour

Tags: javascript, vue.js

for example I have a component like this

```js
var App = {
  data() {
    return {
      mobileCode: '+62',
      mobile: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
      mobileFormat: {
          get: function () {
              return this.mobileCode + this.mobile
          },
          set: function (newValue) {
           if (newValue.length < this.mobileCode.length) {
             this.mobileCode = this.mobileCode
            }
             this.mobile = newValue.substr(this.mobileCode.length)
          }
     }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  The variable enteredValue is {{mobile}}
  <br>
  The variable enteredValue is {{mobileFormat}}
  <el-input v-model="mobileCode"></el-input>
  <el-input v-model="mobileFormat"></el-input>
</div>
```

the problem is, when I delete the value inside the input, I hope that I cannot delete the mobileCode part ('+62').
Value inside the input changed but the data itself not changing.
Is there any workaround for this problem (using vue)?
Is this problem an issue?

Comment: What you want exactly.. can you share sample input / output?

Comment: I want to append the mobileCode to the second input box everytime I edit it. And I don't want to delete the mobileCode inside the input box. Here is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/grxfatp5/4/

Comment: What about applying some mask? There are some vue libs to do it

Comment: It sounds to me like a technical design failure, rather than coding problem. What's your exact goal?

Comment: I've found workaround. https://jsfiddle.net/grxfatp5/5/
This is what my goal is. Is there any other solution?